# How to render node content according to site theme after hook_node_insert/update?

Tags: theming, hooks

How can I get the actual HTML of the node when i am in hook_node_insert/update?
I would like to get the rendered HTML as it should appear in the site and save it somewhere else ...
I am working in drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

So first as the hook_node_update doc says:

> Note that when this hook is invoked, the changes have not yet been
>   written to the database, because a database transaction is still in
>   progress. The transaction is not finalized until the save operation is
>   entirely completed and node_save() goes out of scope. You should not
>   rely on data in the database at this time as it is not updated yet.
>   You should also note that any write/update database queries executed
>   from this hook are also not committed immediately. Check node_save()
>   and db_transaction() for more info.

**Solutions:**

There's a module for that: [hook_post_action](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action)

There's also a short [article](https://www.webomelette.com/drupal-7-post-insert-hooks-shutdown-function) about [drupal_register_shutdown_function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_register_shutdown_function/7.x)